# Get character out of image with python

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch, ocr

I want to detect the characters in a image like this with python:
[image]

In this case the code should return the result '6010001'.

How can I get the result out of this image? What do I need?

For your information, if the solution is a AI-solution, there are about 20.000 labeled images.

Thank you in forward :)

Comment: There may be solutions based on "classical" computer vision (typically based on open-cv) and definitely more interesting solutions based on CNNs or similar. If you search online, you'd find many resources. Anyway, I would suggest you to add a reproducible code here, try something by yourself before asking here, you'll learn much more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question: Are all the pictures of similar nature?
Meaning the Numbers are stamped into a similar material, or are they random pictures with numbers with different techniques (e.g. pen drawn, stamped etc.)?

If they are all quite similar (nice contrast as in sample pic), I would recommend to write your "own" AI, otherwise use an existing neural network / library (as I assume you may want to avoid the pain of creating your own neural network - and tag a lot of pictures).

If they pics are quite "similar", following suggested approach:

- 1. greyscale Image with increase contrast
- 2. define box (greater than a digit), scan over image and count 0s, define by trial valid range to detect a digit, avoid overlaps
- 3. each hit take area, split it in sectors, e.g. 6x4, count 0s
- 4. build a little knowledge base (csv file) of counts per sector for each number from 0-9 (e.g. a string); you will end up in the database with multiple valid strings per each number, just ensure they are unique (otherwise redefine steps 1-3)

In addition I recommend to make yourself a smart knowledge database, meaning: if the digit could not be identified, save digit picture and result. Then make yourself a little review program where it shows you the undefined digits and the result string, you can then manually add them to your knowledge database for the respective number.

Hope it helps. I used the same approach read a lot of different data from screen pictures and store them in a database. Works like a charm.
#better do it yourself than using a standard neural network :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. At first, the images are all existing in grayscale. They are similar and the number is in each images (images size: 640x480px) approximately in the same section (section size: 115x180px) of the picture. So, I would iterate over each pixel with an threshold...Right?

Comment: Maybe use some of the opencv features to get maximum contrast out of your greyscale pictures. Then you would define a rectangle which exceeds the maximal possible size of one digit (e.g. 50x25px), and move pixel by pixel over the area, if the outer frame does not include any 0s (to avoid cutting digits, maybe a little tolerance for picture noise), count the 0s (alternatively sum up the area). Save each picture and write (cv.putText) the count (or sum) result on it. Next: look at the picture and define the digit "hits" - first variable set for digit allocation done! ... (step 2 to follow)

Comment: Step 2: as you have now a nicely cutted single digit, seperate these in sectors, at least 3x3 but better more (I think I used 6 height x 3 wide), count for each sector the 0s and add them to a string, write on complete digit picture and save. Now again have a look through and create yourself a e.g. csv file to allocate each number all found relevant strings. Do this for a few and have good place to start, just ensure no duplication, no string for more than one number (otherwise, increase the sectors and start again, or increase contrast in Picture...).....  hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed anwser. It is possible solution and now, I have an approach to start. Do you think, that a CCN is a possible solution too?

Comment: Apologies, you mean Content-centric networking or Convolutional neural network?

Comment: Convolutional neural network

Comment: Yes, clearly. Have you tried any existing CNN yet? If you want to create one yourself, should be possible too. You mentionned the data set is already labelled. If each digit is seperately tagged (pixel area with number), it should be easy to train your own  neural network yourself (7 digits x 20.000 pictures ~ 14.000 per digit). Otherwise, using an existing one makes more sense. It would be still possible to train it yourself if not each digit is tagged, the result may not be as accurate as you may wish. If you make your own or use existing one really depends on how your dataset is labelled.

Comment: The labelling is not for each character in the image, only for complete image. I don't know, which option is the best one. Where can I find existed models?

Comment: I personally write my own DNN, tailored to specific needs, but not too often. As for me neural networks are a "last mile" approach only, the hundredes of miles towards it I do with handcrafted AI :). A pretrained example you find NYC Coder's answer below, if you want to train one yourself, as you have the labelled data, try Keras (tensorflow). A lot of tutorials are in the web. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opencv-python` and `pytesseract`

```
import cv2
import pytesseract


img = cv2.imread('img3.jpeg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

It doesn't work for all images with text, but works for most.

Comment: does this work for *this image*?